# PHP exec() and command line switches

Tags: php, batch-file, ms-access-2007

So I am using PHP exec() to run a batch file on my server:

echo exec("printCountries.bat");

The batch file opens Microsoft Access 2007 and runs a macro to print a form and then close Access:

START /MIN  /B  msaccess.exe "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\reports.accdb" /X printCountries

I can run the batch file from the command line successfully and the form prints to our network printer (this is for a company intranet) and closes Access. But when I run the PHP script, the batch file only runs the Access Process but does not perform the command line switches or open the database file.

I have configured PHP to have the right privileges on IIS, I am just stumped as to why the command line switches don't work and the batch file won't open the database.

Any ideas?

here is the echo output:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scale>START /MIN /B msaccess.exe "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\reports.accdb" /X printCountries

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have some access rights problem.

Did you try to run in PHP this `echo exec("whoami");`
What username you get?
Something like `"nt authority\iusr"` ?

You have to give to the default IIS user (i.e. IIS_IUSRS) full access to the path that your scripts lives.

In addition you can change (only TEMPORARILY huh?) the default application pool user from `ApplicationPoolIdentity` to `LocalService` or `LocalSystem` to test the results...

If I were you, I would created a new Application in IIS then I would created a new Application Pool and I would assigned it to this app. Then I created a new user that will have access to all the appropriate directories (web dir and where the bat is located).

If nothing of the above worked I would test my php application from my command line (locally) using the `php` command in my local command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I am neither good with PHP, nor with Access. However, when you invoke the batch file from PHP, please create an instance of cmd.exe and pass "/c printCountries.bat" to cmd.exe. In other words, the command run by PHP exec should look something like this (assuming PATH is set correctly):

```
cmd.exe /c printCountries.bat
```

Also, inside printContries.bat, I think you will need to wait until the access process terminates. So it should look like

```
START /WAIT /MIN /B msaccess.exe "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\system\reports.accdb" /X printCountries
```